# After I add NuGet.Core package to my csproj as PackageReference, I have no any effect

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli

After I add `NuGet.Core` package to my csproj as PackageReference, I have no any effect. Next I describe reproduction steps and my project folder content. My question: am I doing something wrong way or it is a dotnet cli bug? I registered an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7268) and will be track both - this question and the issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `dotnet new console`
2. Change `TargetFramework` in `csproj` file to `net461`
3. `dotnet add package NuGet.Core`
4. Add `using NuGet` to `Program.cs`  (this namespace is exists in NuGet.Core Assembly, I checked)
5. `dotnet restore`
6. `dotnet build`

**Result:** an error "The type or namespace name 'NuGet' could not be found".

**Full content of my project dir:**

nuget-tree.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Core" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using NuGet;

namespace nuget_tree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**.NET CLI Tools Version:** I'm tried on both: `1.0.4` and `2.0.0-preview2-25407-01`

Comment: what's the name of your csproj file?

Comment: NugetTree.csproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that problem is not in dotnet CLI, but in nuget. I do following:

1. Created a Console Application in Visual Studio 2015
2. In Package Manager Console: `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Xdt -Version 2.1.0`
3. `PM> Install-Package NuGet.Core -Version 2.13.1`

That is worked fine. But if I installed latest version of `NuGet.Core` then in packages dir in NuGet.Core subfolder there is no `lib` folder with assembly. And so I can't reference it in project. That is all seems weird. Then **I decided to clear nuget cache. And this solves my problem.** After cache was cleared I can create a new project and successfully use latest NuGet.Core.

To clear cache I used:

- `nuget locals all -list` - list the local caches
- `nuget locals all -clear` - clear all caches